# Sax: XMLReader: Streaming and converting CSV to Xml and validating the result at the same time

Tags: java, xml, csv, streaming, sax

I have to transform some CSV files (each > 600 MB) to XML while validating the end result with an XSD on the fly.

Because of the size of each file I'm using InputStreams to read the content and OutpuStreams to stream the result back to my clients as XML.

Let's start then with the easy part... (pseudocode)

```
void transform(final InputStream CSVCustomerStream, final OutputStream outputStream) {
       outputStream.write("<customers>")
       foreach csvCustomerRow in CSVCustomerStream {
            String xmlCustomerRow = csvCustomerRow.toXML();
            outputStream.write(xmlCustomerRow.getBytes();
       }
       outputStream.write("</customers>")

       **MISSING_XMLVALIDATOR.parse(outputStream);**
}
```

So far, each row of my source CSV file is transformed to xml and then written to the outputstream.

Easy enough.

The part though, where the xml is actually validated is still missing.

For this I looked into [XMLReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/XMLReader.html)'s parse() method. The only problem with that, is the fact that parse() only accepts InputSources, while at the same time I'm streaming the content I'd like to be validated to an OutputStream.

Of course, after reading the whole CSV content, I could turn the OutputStream into an InputStream via

```
 new ByteArrayInputStream((outputstream).toByteArray())
```

but that would immediately bring 600 MB worth of XML back into memory, defying the whole purpose of streaming.

PS: I have no control over the exact implementation of the OutputStream since my code runs as a REST-webservice

```
    return Response.ok(new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) throws Exception {
            ....     loading and transforming csv ...

        }
    }).build();
```

Comment: Before getting into something more evolved, the first question I would ask myself would be: are the records independent of each other (typically in batch files they are)? If the answer is yes (i.e., for example, a xmlCustomerRow is self contained), then why not validate each row as it is created? A counter example might be where you would want to enforce uniqueness of some fields across the entire file, hence you want to use a key/keyref at the customers element level.

Comment: Yes, they are independent of each other, exactly as you said. I had a similar idea about validating each row separately, but since the defining XSD describes the document as a whole I don't see the mechanics of this. If I would throw a single xml customer element at the XSD, I thought, it might complain about incomplete/missing tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034809/sax-xmlreader-streaming-and-converting-csv-to-xml-and-validating-the-result-at#comment21132415_15034809), let me put forward the "worst" possible scenario, one where the XSD is authored as a Russian Doll (i.e. except for a document root, all other element and types are defined locally). Because of this style, there is no way to validate the xmlCustomerRow against the XSD, since there is no global element declaration which would match your tag (assume `customer`).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="customers">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="customer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>

                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Still, the solution is not that complicated. Take a look at this modified XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="customers">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="customer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:complexType>

                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="customer">
        <xsd:complexType>

        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

For this setup, you only need to open the original XSD as an XML, clone the `customer` element, remove its minOccurs/maxOccurs attribute, and then insert it as a child of the `schema` (it would be the document element in the XML). The idea here is that you could do a refactoring on the fly, or manually, etc.

There's always a possibility that you wouldn't have to do anything i.e. if the `customer` element is already global, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="customers">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="customer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="customer">
        <xsd:complexType>

        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Other complications may arise, depending on how your XSD really looks like, but I can assure you that there could be nothing in there which would stop you from doing whatever refactoring you may need to achieve exactly what you want.

I am rather of the opinion that having the ability to validate each record independently beats anything else. More so, for a massive file running on a multi-core/CPU machine, you could parallelize your validation, which would make more efficient use of resources to achieve increased throughput.

Comment: The customer-XSD is very simple and your idea should work immediately! Building on this I could even start by separating the customerS and customer definition into two single schemas letting the customerS part include the customer-definition. Only the customer definition is used for validation during runtime. That should make the code more readable. But what about the other way around: Take the customer-element, decorate it with the missing opening/closing tags and use the current XSD without any modifications?

Comment: @simou you have to keep it as simple as possible. If it is possible, use a single file, having customers and customer as global elements. If I understand correctly, your `other way around` is really a variant of my last sample XSD so yes, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that tests will be sufficient to assure that your conversion produces XML that validates with the given XSD, or that (as Petru Gardea said in a comment) you can validate piecemeal using temporary strings.

But assuming that you actually have to validate on the fly, there are some tricks you can try, basically by manipulating streams.

You are producing an `OutputStream` that presumably you want to send to your client, and you have a process that you know how to do that needs an `InputStream` (actually the `Reader` interfaces might make some of this easier, but the fixes are parallel).

This means that you have to "tee" the `OutputStream`, i.e., duplicate it on-the-fly so you can send one stream to the client and use the copy for validation parsing.  And you need to get an `InputStream` from your copied `OutputStream`.

For the "tee" process, you should consider Apache Commons [TeeOutputStream](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html), and for conversion from output to input, you should probably look at [PipedInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedInputStream.html) and [PipedOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedOutputStream.html).

Comment: I guess tests should be enough, but to stay out of the blame-game.... if something goes wrong. PipedXXXputStream shouldn't be used together when participating in the same thread, that's according to the JavaDoc, so I wasn't sure about that.

Comment: Yes, this should be multithreaded, and that does complicate things.  But it definitely can be done.  It's from a few jobs back, so I don't have the code, but I've done essentially the same thing using PipedXxxStream (or maybe Readers/Writers) and a homegrown "tee" filter.